# Back button does not appear in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to simply add a back button to the view controller, when accessed from a TableView in my app.

I have embedded the resulting ViewController within the navigation controller, and the back button is simply supposed to appear as documentation notes, but it does not...

[image]

Comment: Delete the middle navigation controller, only the table view should be embedded in Navigation controller

Comment: you don't need navigation controller in the middle.

Comment: is there any purpose having an additional nav controller for Individ Chat VC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the UINavigationController between FriendsViewController and IndividualChatController.

When you push a new navigationController, it creates a new navigation stack with its own navigationBar and therefore you don't see a back button in the navigationBar